# Counting loops on countable graph embedded on flat torus

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-embeddings

I was wondering about the research on countable connected graphs on compact surfaces, in particular the flat torus. In my considerations, I started with the flat torus view by $\mathbb{T}=[0,1]^2/{\sim}$, where $\sim$ is the identification of opposite sides.

Draw lines cutting the square into $4$ equals squares and draw a vertex where two lines meet. This gives a Graph consisting of one vertex and 2 loops embedded in $\mathbb{T}$. Inductively, proceed with subdiving each square of the previous step into $4$ identical squares.

In the limit, this gives a countable graph $G$ embedded in $\mathbb{T}$. If I am not completely mistaken, $G$ is transitive. Now I want to count the cycles in $G$ starting from some (and therefore any) vertex $v\in G$ with length smaller then some $k\in \mathbb{N}$. It looks like this is equivalent to counting rooted cycles in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ but I do not manage to grasp the structure since the area of the squares shrinks to zero and so does the length of the edges after embedding.

Can I approach this as is done for the integer lattice via the dual graph and counting number of connected areas of squares with a fixed boundary length? Or am I missing some subtleties here? My intuition breaks down due to the strange geometry of the lengths/areas and finite length paths at some stage of the inductive construction which grow exonzntially to infinity when continuing the subdivisions.

Comment: What do you mean by "In the limit, this gives a countable graph $G$ embedded in $\mathbb T$"? What kind of limit and what kind of embedding are these?

Comment: "In the limit" means that you let continue the inductive construction like for example for the Cantor set. The embedding simply means, that the construction is done on the torus and so at any step the resltuing (finite) graph is embedded in $\mathbb{T}$. You could also see it as an abstract growing family of $4-regular graphs related by subsequent graphs being related by a Graph minor property.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. An embedding is usually a map that maps every vertex of the graph to a point in some space. If that's how you're using the term, I don't see which map you're referring to. All I see is a series of finite graphs embedded in $\mathbb T$. I think you're going to have to be more precise about what you mean by taking "the limit" of these graphs and about how this limiting graph is embedded in $\mathbb T$.

Comment: In the case of the Cantor set, the limit is precisely defined. In each step, you remove certain sets of points, and the limit is the set that remains after all these sets have been removed, i.e. the intersection of the sets remaining at each finite stage. I don't see a definition of this kind for your limit.

Comment: The inductive construction gives a recursion of the form $G_{n} = T^n(G_0)$ where $G_0$ is the graph with 1 vertex and 2 loops, which I discribed above. My limit is then in the discrete topology in the set of at most countable graphs given by $\lim{n\to\infty} T^n(G_0)$ and its embedding also as a limit of embeddings of the $T^n(G_0)$ in the topology of continuous embeddings from the set of graphs into the torus.

Comment: In a discrete topology, only eventually constant sequences have a limit (since the set containing only the limit is open and the sequence has to eventually end up in every open set). Your sequence of graphs is clearly not eventually constant.

Comment: @Jfischer, Apparently, you can consider that $V(G)$ is the union of vertices of all your finite graphs. But what is $E(G)$? You need to define it.

Comment: @kabenyuk $E(G)$ are all the line segments between two vertices. But I am currently trying to figure out the right topology to obtain a limit. Maybe some growing square windows (with identification of the sides) as is done for infinite volume Gibbs measures plus a renonormalization of the volume...